# How to disable the internet in wdio mocha selenium?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, wdio, wdio-v6

I am using the below codes in my script but the internet is **not getting disconnected.**

###### 1st try:

> ```
>        await browser.setNetworkConditions({
>         latency: 0,
>         throughput: 0,
>         offline: true
>     });
> ```

###### 2nd try:

> ```
>   browser.setNetworkConnection(0)// airplane mode off, wifi off, data off
> ```

###### 3rd try:

> ```
>  await browser.throttle({
>        offline: true,
>         downloadThroughput: 200 * 1024 / 8,
>         uploadThroughput: 200 * 1024 / 8,
>         latency: 20
>     })
> ```

Some links I have found in wdio official documentation but none of them are working.

- [browser.throttle](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/throttle/)
- [setNetworkConnection](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/mobile/setNetworkConnection.html)
- [setnetworkconditions](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/chromium/#setnetworkconditions)

Could anyone suggest to me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

visiting the https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/throttle/ they state the following "*There are many presets available with default configurations for ease of use. They are offline, GPRS, Regular2G, Good2G, Regular3G, Good3G, Regular4G, DSL, WiFi, online.*". By looking here: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/6824e4eb118a8d20685f12f4bc42f13fd56f8a25/packages/webdriverio/src/commands/browser/throttle.js#L29 we can determine that the offline preset they use is:

```
'offline': {
    offline: true,
    downloadThroughput: 0,
    uploadThroughput: 0,
    latency: 1
}
```

So I would suggest trying the following:

```
 await browser.throttle({
    offline: true,
    downloadThroughput: 0,
    uploadThroughput: 0,
    latency: 1
})
```

Let me know if this helps!